# EXCEL: Need cross dependence on cells to work a simple formula

Tags: excel, vba

Essentially what I need to do is Type a number into cell A1 and have that reflect cell B and C. Then type into B and have that reflect A and C. And finally type into C and have that reflect A and B.

(Obviously They can't all depend on each other automatically, so they have to send the info to the other two cells only after completing a manual entry of a value in either of the 3 cells.)

Case:

A1=1  ,    B2=60   , C1=3600

Respectively - Hours, Minutes, Seconds.

What I need is to type 5400 into C1 and end up with 90 in B1, and 1.5 in A1.
After that if type 2 in A1, end up with 120 in B1 and 7200 in C1.
Etc.

Thx in advance. (don't know if it need VBA)

Btw does anybody know of a spreadsheet web service that doesn't have a downloads, annoying registrations etc. Would have been alot faster if i linked something back here, that people don't need to login and register to see as an example...

Comment: `don't know if it need VBA` - it needs VBA. Have you already tried something? If not, look into [Worksheet_Change event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: two things: 1. Indeed, you need VBA (easier, cheaper, faster, simpler, etc). 2. Please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: My tech level is pretty low so I'm using a manual method that takes another row. I enter what i need in 1 cell then in the next say what it is (hour, minute, second), Data validate it and goes to respected result cells. Thats why I'm looking into a smoother way to accomplish it. Google can't be too helpful probably because I can't figure out the precise tech term for the function I'm looking for.

Comment: ... I found the answer, I don't have enough REP to answer my own question right away, I'll do it after the WAIT period expires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution for future reference. Kudos to ragulduy for it.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
If Not Intersect(target, Range("A1:C1")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        Range("B1") = Range("A1") * 60
        Range("C1") = Range("A1") * 3600
    ElseIf target.Address = "$B$1" Then
        Range("A1") = Range("B1") / 60
        Range("C1") = Range("B1") * 60
    ElseIf target.Address = "$C$1" Then
        Range("A1") = Range("C1") / 3600
        Range("B1") = Range("C1") / 60
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

Tags: Co-dependent cells, Co dependent cells, Cell cross reference, Cross-reference cell, Multi Dependent cell